# Can I run startup code on a JEE server prior to any messages being consumed, web calls

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, resource-adapter

I have a database script that runs DDL and takes pessimistic locks, which does database maintenance.  I need to run this script preferably when the application is (re)started.  But if any of the MDBs or Web Service calls function they will lock with the maintenace script, I need to ensure that this code runs to completion prior to ANY MDB or Web Service call is processed.

Is there anything in the JEE that guarantees this occurs?  The best solution I've seen is creating a resource adapter for the EAR, but I can't find anything that guarantees this startup code completes prior to the other beans/MDBs/Servlets kick off.  I'm trying to avoid an application level lock on database access just to achieve maintenance, but perhaps that is the only way.

I've also seen an AfterDeploymentValidation event on the container, from the description it looks like it might do the job, but I can't find any doco to confirm.

Comment: Maybe this will answer your question: [Seven ways to get things started. Java EE Startup Classes with GlassFish and WebLogic](http://blog.eisele.net/2010/12/seven-ways-to-get-things-started-java.html)

Comment: Thats what i've been working from, but I've confirmed that using the @Startup bean Interceptor will allow calls to be processed.  I wanted to use the servlet context, but that only guarantees that web service calls won't be processed.  AfterDeploymentValidation seems promising, but I can't confirm in doco that it's guaranteed to run before MDBs or WARs begin processing.

Comment: What about a ServletContextListener? http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html

Comment: my concern is that only guarantees to run prior to web service calls being processed by the WAR.  I also have Message Driven Beans in my EAR which might start processing too.